# Resuming for loop if JSONException occurs

Tags: java, json

Im parsing the json response from foursquare. There are some json objects that are missing so I catched it. But how do you continue a for loop if an exception occurs;

```
if (length > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        JSONObject venueObject = venues.getJSONObject(i);

        String id = venueObject.getString("id");
        String name = venueObject.getString("name");

        JSONObject location = venueObject.getJSONObject("location");
        String lat = String.valueOf(location.getDouble("lat"));
        String lng = String.valueOf(location.getDouble("lng"));

        HashMap<String, String> venue = new HashMap<>();
        venue.put("id", id);
        venue.put("name", name);
        venue.put("lat", lat);
        venue.put("lng", lng);

        String address = "";
        try {
            JSONArray addressArray = location.getJSONArray("formattedAddress");
            address = addressArray.getString(i);
        } catch (JSONException j) {
            address = location.getString("country");
        } finally {
            venue.put("address", address);
            venueList.add(venue);

            //continue for loop somehow
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say some objects are missing, would it be better to configure your mappings to ignore missing properties?  Once you've mapped everything as Java objects, you can then validate as required.

Comment: i can't ignore the address since it's required for my app. Since the location always has a country JSON object, im getting that as an alternative if the formattedAddress is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything - if a JSONException is thrown is thrown, the catch and finally blocks execute and the code continues executing as before, so the for loop continues.

One thing though - if you expect some JSON objects to be absent, it would be better to check before trying to access them than to access them and catch the exception.